# Google News RSS feed returning a didFailWithError -1002 code

Tags: iphone, sdk, error-handling, rss

I am downloading Google news as an RSS feed.  If I view in a browser, everything works fine.  But when I try to download as a readable file using the following code I get a "-1002" error.  Any ideas?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];


path = @"feed://news.google.com/news?pz=1&jfkl=true&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&q=oslo&cf=all&output=rss";
urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: path]];
urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
[urlConnection release];


}

#pragma mark Download RSS

// Start connection and download
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");

rssData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)dataDownloaded {

NSLog(@"didReceiveData");

[rssData appendData:dataDownloaded];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error code %i", [error code]];
NSLog(@"error: %@", errorString);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change feed:// to http:// and it will work.